# Handling Eventsource using PHP and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, php, jquery

I have created a fileWatcher(running as a service) in C# which calls PHP script through URL whenever there is a change in Folder.

I want to load the web page with new data when there is change in file.
I have tried doing this using javascript Eventsource by calling PHP and echoing by C# whenever there is change in file but no luck.

Any suggestions how would I tackle this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Jeff If there was filewatcher service in PHP, I would have created on PHP and not on C# and things were simpler.

Comment: Your question isn't off-topic because of any technology that exists in PHP or C# or not - it's off-topic because it's broad to the point of essentially asking someone to write an entire application for you.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I am need the way to solve this and not asking for any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by checking file size every minute and responding to event source. Only overhead is checking file every 1 minute.